# How to separate the roots of a polynom

Tags: algorithm, math

How to separate the roots of a polynom ?

The degree of the polynom is n (10 < n < 20) and the polynom has the same number of roots as it's degree. All roots are real.

I need to separate the roots before using Newton/Raphson or other numerical well known methods to find the roots.
I've learned a long time ago that there are methods to separate the roots but I have lost my notes and I don't remember it.

I don't want any mathematica/maple or math software library solutions because I have to implement it in a software.

Comment: The [Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/) site may be more helpful in this case.

Comment: The problem is related to numerical analysis software engeneering. it's at the crossroads of math and sofware ingeneering. Is there a tag for this domain? Or can I crosspost it in the two sites?

Comment: Never crosspost. Even though personally I think this falls more in the field of maths.

Comment: For your degree range for example the Jenkins-Traub algorithms will reliably and efficiently find all roots of the polynomial, without prior localization. Do you have any reason to suspect numerical problems, for instance because of close clusters of solutions?

Comment: I don't suspect problems, I will try your solution.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you are thinking of a [Sturm sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem)?

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to construct [Sturm chain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem) f0(x) = f(x), f1(x), ... , fs(x) in the range [a,b] and to count number of changes of the sign in this chain in boundary points a and b: Va - Vb where

Va = changes of sign in chain f0(a) = f(a), f1(a), ... , fs(a)

Vb = changes of sign in chain f0(b) = f(b), f1(b), ... , fs(b)

Va-Vb is the number of different roots of this polynomial in range (a,b). You can divide your domain into ranges and apply this procedure in each of them.

Now the last question is how to construct such a chain. Common way to do it is to use modification of [Euclidean Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm), that is:

f0(x) = f(x)
f1(x) = f'(x)

and the next terms are retrieved from:

f0(x) = q1(x)f1(x) - f2(x)
...
fk-1(x) = qk(x)fk(x) - fk+1(x)
...
fs-1(x) = qs(x)fs(x)

This is a Sturm chain in any range [a,b] where f(a) != 0 != f(b). Alternatively you might search for a [Legendre polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials) which can be used to construct Sturm chain. You might also want to look at the [Budan-Fourier](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Budan-Fourier_theorem) theorem.

Answer (score 1):

The Vincent-Akritas method finds provably all real roots via enclosing rational intervals by recursively determining the continued fraction expansion of the roots.

---

Dedieu-Yakoubsohn published the Bisection-Exclusion principle that is a combination of Dandelin-Graeffe root squaring iterations and root radius estimates to reliably locate all roots on the real line or in the complex plane.

Description of the simple form of the exclusion algorithm at (http://algo.inria.fr/seminars/sem92-93/yakoubsohn.ps‎) (Postscript viewer required)

[Published paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jco.2005.06.007) on a more efficient form of the algorithm.

---

The Durand-Kerner (and also the Aberth-Ehrlich) method finds all roots of a polynomial simultaneously, thus also not omitting any root. Additionally, the offsets of the method allow to determine root-enclosing disks in the complex plane.